# Union within union, and broken matrix addition

Tags: c, directx, unions

XMFLOAT4X4 makes use of a union within a union for the matrix definition, but when I attempt the same method with, and without, the extra union I get varied results in access patterns. I'm not sure if this is in the initialization of the unions, or where I might being going wrong in the implementation. In my code the single union was not working, but now in this code the dual union is not working. Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union{
    union{
        struct{float xx,xy,xz,xw, yx,yy,yz,yw, zx,zy,zz,zw, wx,wy,wz,ww;};
        float m[4][4];
    };
}Mat4DoubleUnion;

typedef union{
    struct{float xx,xy,xz,xw, yx,yy,yz,yw, zx,zy,zz,zw, wx,wy,wz,ww;};
    float m[4][4];
}Mat4SingleUnion;

int main(void){
    Mat4SingleUnion mat_single_1 = 
    {1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1};
    Mat4SingleUnion mat_single_2 = 
    {1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1};
    Mat4DoubleUnion mat_double_1 = 
    {1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1};
    Mat4DoubleUnion mat_double_2 = 
    {1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1};

    Mat4DoubleUnion out_double;
    Mat4SingleUnion out_single;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
            out_double.m[i][j] = mat_double_1.m[i][j] + mat_double_2.m[i][j];
            out_single.m[i][j] = mat_single_1.m[i][j] + mat_single_2.m[i][j];
        }
        printf("Double Union\n");
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
            printf("[%f  %f  %f  %f]\n", out_double.m[i][0], out_double.m[i][1], out_double.m[i][2], out_double.m[i][3]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("Single Union\n");
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
            printf("[%f  %f  %f  %f]\n", out_single.m[i][0], out_single.m[i][1], out_single.m[i][2], out_single.m[i][3]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

with output given below. You can notice the large numbers that arise throughout the looping process, and when you reach the end the sum of the two matrices is not the correct output.

```
Double Union
[2.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  -170141183460469231731687303715884105728.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[304728612076653271699817077145600.000000  18030524136642386826155261952.000000  269154975309704986624.000000  73908519441581681410048.000000]

Single Union
[2.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]

Double Union
[2.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  2.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[304728612076653271699817077145600.000000  18030524136642386826155261952.000000  269154975309704986624.000000  73908519441581681410048.000000]

Single Union
[2.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  2.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]

Double Union
[2.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  2.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  2.000000  0.000000]
[304728612076653271699817077145600.000000  18030524136642386826155261952.000000  269154975309704986624.000000  73908519441581681410048.000000]

Single Union
[2.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  2.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  2.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]

Double Union
[2.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  2.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  2.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  2.000000]

Single Union
[2.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  2.000000  0.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  2.000000  0.000000]
[0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  2.000000]
```

Comment: Show both sets of code, show the code that uses them, and show the behaviors of those two sets of code. For example, for both sets of code, show code that assigns values to all of the individual elements and prints the values of all the array elements, as well as showing the values shown by the `offsetof` macro for the various elements and the `sizeof` the union and the struct. It ight also be useful to initialize the entire memory of the union to zero bytes, then assign a value to one element, then dump the bytes of the union’s memory. Generally, you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note that anonymous structs are not a valid C++, and that using union to "unpack" matrix fields (store value `m[0][0]` and then access `xx`) would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this two lines. It's a very subtle use before initiation problem.

```
Mat4DoubleUnion out_double; memset(&out_double, 0, sizeof(out_double));
Mat4SingleUnion out_single; memset(&out_single, 0, sizeof(out_single));
```

In each outer loop, you only initiate one row of out_single and out_double, so the rest of row is garbage. In last outer loop, all rows are properly initiated, the output is correct. I think the uninitiated use is undefined behave, so...

you can try memory check tool valgrind, will tell a lot information in this case:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go. I haven't worked a ton with c style arrays. C++ spoils you with vectors and friends.